# Java - Using swingUtlities.invokeLater frrom another class?

Tags: java, swing, jetty

I'm writing an application that uses Websockets to communicate. I have used Jetty for my Websocket client and I have it sending and receiving messages fine. I have a onMessage method that receives messages, and it is able to print them just fine, however I'm not quite sure how to get it to call back to my MainUI thread.

I have been reading up on swingUtlitties.invokeLater but I don't quite understand how I get it to work from another class & thread.

Thx

Comment: `invokeLater()` should work from any thread or class, that's what it's for.  However I have a concern about mixing Swing and Jetty/web-servers.  Are you *SURE* that's what you want to do?  Could you describe your application from a higher level so we can check this isn't a misunderstanding?

Comment: My application just has several buttons that send Websocket messages to a server. I want to used the messages I receive to provide feedback to the buttons (so if button 1 is activated, it would have maybe a green border around the button).

Comment: OK, and I assume that Jetty is only involved on the server side?  You said "Jetty client" and that confuses me.

Comment: @markspace he could be using Jetty's WebSocket Client library (no server).  Even so, the websocket client starts a bunch of threads (in a thread pool) to handle its processing.

Comment: @markspace Jetty has (at last count) 4 stand alone client libraries: http high level client (http/1.1, http/2, fcgi, h2c, etc), http/2 low level client (access to raw http/2 streams/frames), native websocket client, jsr356 websocket client.

Comment: @JoakimErdfelt I'm unfamiliar with Jetty so that's good info. jdm55: I think the best way would be to get this working without Swing, just make sure you can send the messages to the server that you want.  Then show us the working code, and ask how to use Swing where you are having trouble.

Answer (score 0):

Use a `SwingWorker` to run your Socket connection in a separate Thread. The `SwingWorker` has methods that allow you to "publish" result back to the GUI as they become available.

Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Concurrency](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/interim.html) for background information on how the `Event Dispatch Thread (EDT)` works in Swing. The section on `Tasks That Have Interim Rsults` has an example of using the `SwingWorker`

Comment: Looks like SwingWorker is the way. Cheers mate!

Comment: @jdm555 glad it help. Don't forget to "accept" the answer by clicking on the checkmark so people know the problem has been solved. (same for you other questions).

Comment: Will do. My socket is in a different class. Do I Implement SwingWorker in the socket class or in the MainUI class? I've got it in the MainUI class atm, and I'm not sure how to access the publish method from my onMsg event in my socket class.

Comment: The SwingWorker is really just a separate Thread with added methods that allow you to update the GUI. So you need to open the Socket in the SwingWorker.